# Is there any benefit to not including JS & CSS files on every page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My script needs jQuery, Bootstrap and some plugins in order to work, that's 5 JS and 4 CSS files which are included on every page of my site. Not every page, however, uses jQuery and Bootstrap's JavaScript/CSS, so I can remove these files from the head of those pages that do not need them. Is there any benefit to doing so?

Comment: Yes there's benefit to lightening the page load requirements for browser

Comment: Bootstrap CSS is commonly used to style the page frame of a site. Not including it on particular pages suggests that the page is not styled like the rest. This could cause some visual discontinuity. Is that what you intend?

Comment: I did not mean to say I won't include the main Bootstrap CSS. There are Bootstrap plugins that have their own JS/CSS.

Comment: Makes sense. See my answer for a full response, but in short I wholeheartedly encourage you to exclude JS/CSS from pages where it's not needed.

Comment: For those that were discussing my answer, I went ahead and deleted it because in retrospect I agree it does not accurately answer the original question of "Is there any benefit...".  While I believe one could argue that the optimization benefits are low to negligible, I agree that there are benefits to be seen from the delivery perspective, even if there are other variables worth considering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. Don't load what you don't need.

Think about what happens when you include extraneous resources on a page, particularly in the document head. Before any content is rendered to the screen, the browser must download, parse, and execute these resources. If they link to other resources, those must be loaded as well. This blocks page rendering. This is bad. This forces the browser to do unnecessary work when it could be spending that time and CPU on tasks relevant to the loading of the page.

One could argue that it doesn't matter if you include these resources unnecessarily because of browser caching. I don't think this is a valid argument because users could access the page directly with a cold cache. Their experience would be impeded by the extra JS/CSS. One could then argue that the next page the user visits that does actually need those resources will be faster because the resources are served from cache. That's true, but it doesn't need to adversely affect the first page. Resource prefetching is a common practice but it needs to be done without making pages slower. Do it asynchronously after page load instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The benefit will be that the browser won't need to parse them, and won't need to allocate memory for the entities they generate - either CSS classes or JS objects & variables.

Answer (score 0):

Removing js and css files that you never use in that page increase your page speed. Page Speed is important for search engines and your users. You need to remove them.